# How to fix the position of a picture on a fixed page, in MS Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, pictures, layout

I took advantage of 'fix position on page' layout option of Microsoft Word 2013 for fixing the position of a picture in the page, but it only pays attention to the position of paper related to page, but not related to a fixed page.

As an example; fix the position of an image which is as big as a total page on your document, then write in its previous page as much as it becomes full and need a new page, you will see that your picture will be pushed front by one page! But you had fixed it!!

I would like to fix a picture; what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you can do what you want:

1. Create a **text-box**.
2. Insert your **picture inside** that text-box and resize it to your liking.
3. You can turn off the text-box **border** if you want to make it invisible.
4. In text-box properties, you can specify **position** (advanced) as absolute, relative to page.
5. With the text-box **Layout** option, wrappings style, you can control how the text flows in relation to the box, so you can avoid the problem you had before.